# How to ask user for permission before NBug report submission

Tags: c#, nbug

How to ask user for permission before NBug report submission?

I can't seem to find this in the documentation or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NBug is designed to submit bug reports automatically with minimal user interference hence it doesn't have any dialog/method to ask user for permission.

I guess the most logical thing would be to indicate that you'll be collecting anonymous crash data in your app EULA.

Comment: In that case, consider this a feature request. It would be nice if it was at least an option.

Comment: Noted. Possible for future 2.0 release.